# Simple grammar give ValueError in Python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm new to Python, nltk and nlp. I have written simple grammar. But when running the program it gives below error. Please help me to solve this error

Grammar:-

```
S -> NP
NP -> PN|PRO|D[NUM=?n] N[NUM=?n]|D[NUM=?n] A N[NUM=?n]|D[NUM=?n] N[NUM=?n] PP|QP N[NUM=?n]|A N[NUM=?n]|D[NUM=?n] NOM PP|D[NUM=?n] NOM
PP -> P NP
D[NUM=sg] -> 'a'
D -> 'the'
N[NUM=sg] -> 'boy'|'girl'|'room'|'garden'|'hair'
N[NUM=pl] -> 'dogs'|'cats'
PN -> 'saumya'|'dinesh'
PRO -> 'she'|'he'|'we'
A -> 'tall'|'naughty'|'long'|'three'|'black'
P -> 'with'|'in'|'from'|'at'
QP -> 'some'
NOM -> A NOM|N[NUM=?n]
```

Code:-

```
import nltk

grammar = nltk.data.load('file:english_grammer.cfg')
rdparser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar)
sent = "a dogs".split()
trees = rdparser.parse(sent)

for tree in trees: print (tree)
```

Error:-

ValueError: Expected a nonterminal, found: [NUM=?n] N[NUM=?n]|D[NUM=?n] A N[NUM=?n]|D[NUM=?n] N[NUM=?n] PP|QP N[NUM=?n]|A N[NUM=?n]|D[NUM=?n] NOM PP|D[NUM=?n] NOM

Comment: please also post the full error traceback from your code.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think NLTK CFG grammar readers can read the format of your CFG with square brackets.

First let's try a CFG grammar without the square brackets:

```
from nltk.grammar import CFG

grammar_string = '''
S -> NP
PP -> P NP
D -> 'the'
PN -> 'saumya'|'dinesh'
PRO -> 'she'|'he'|'we'
A -> 'tall'|'naughty'|'long'|'three'|'black'
P -> 'with'|'in'|'from'|'at'
QP -> 'some'
'''

grammar = CFG.fromstring(grammar_string)
print grammar
```

[out]:

```
Grammar with 18 productions (start state = S)
    S -> NP
    PP -> P NP
    D -> 'the'
    PN -> 'saumya'
    PN -> 'dinesh'
    PRO -> 'she'
    PRO -> 'he'
    PRO -> 'we'
    A -> 'tall'
    A -> 'naughty'
    A -> 'long'
    A -> 'three'
    A -> 'black'
    P -> 'with'
    P -> 'in'
    P -> 'from'
    P -> 'at'
    QP -> 'some'
```

Now let's put the square brackets in:

```
from nltk.grammar import CFG

grammar_string = '''
S -> NP
PP -> P NP
D -> 'the'
PN -> 'saumya'|'dinesh'
PRO -> 'she'|'he'|'we'
A -> 'tall'|'naughty'|'long'|'three'|'black'
P -> 'with'|'in'|'from'|'at'
QP -> 'some'
N[NUM=sg] -> 'boy'|'girl'|'room'|'garden'|'hair'
N[NUM=pl] -> 'dogs'|'cats'
'''

grammar = CFG.fromstring(grammar_string)
print grammar
```

[out]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    grammar = CFG.fromstring(grammar_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/grammar.py", line 519, in fromstring
    encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/grammar.py", line 1273, in read_grammar
    (linenum+1, line, e))
ValueError: Unable to parse line 10: N[NUM=sg] -> 'boy'|'girl'|'room'|'garden'|'hair'
Expected an arrow
```

**Going back to your grammar, it seems like you're using the square brackets to denote constraints or uncontraints, so the solution would be**:

- Using underscore for contrainted non-terminals and
- to make a rule for unconstrainted non-terminals

So your cfg rules will look as such:

```
from nltk.parse import RecursiveDescentParser
from nltk.grammar import CFG

grammar_string = '''
S -> NP
NP -> PN | PRO | D N | D A N | D N PP | QP N | A N | D NOM PP | D NOM

PP -> P NP
PN -> 'saumya'|'dinesh'
PRO -> 'she'|'he'|'we'
A -> 'tall'|'naughty'|'long'|'three'|'black'
P -> 'with'|'in'|'from'|'at'
QP -> 'some'

D -> D_def | D_sg
D_def -> 'the'
D_sg -> 'a'

N -> N_sg | N_pl
N_sg -> 'boy'|'girl'|'room'|'garden'|'hair'
N_pl -> 'dogs'|'cats'
'''

grammar = CFG.fromstring(grammar_string)

rdparser = RecursiveDescentParser(grammar)
sent = "a dogs".split()
trees = rdparser.parse(sent)

for tree in trees:
    print (tree)
```

[out]:

```
(S (NP (D (D_sg a)) (N (N_pl dogs))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually what I want is to rejects the following ill formed sentences from my grammar.
(i).a dogs
(ii).three girl
(iii).the cats from he

Comment: The post resolves the error you posted. so i guess the rest is your homework, you'll be able to do it keeping in mind that brackets are not allow in the non-terminals and no constraints in the cfg of the NLTK API. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use NLTK's feature grammars, which do use the square bracket syntax to denote features and feature agreement. NLTK's parser to use feature grammars is the FeatureEarleyChartParser (as opposed to RecursiveDescentParser).

From the [NLTK documentation](http://www.nltk.org/howto/featgram.html):

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import grammar, parse
>>> g = """
... % start DP
... DP[AGR=?a] -> D[AGR=?a] N[AGR=?a]
... D[AGR=[NUM='sg', PERS=3]] -> 'this' | 'that'
... D[AGR=[NUM='pl', PERS=3]] -> 'these' | 'those'
... D[AGR=[NUM='pl', PERS=1]] -> 'we'
... D[AGR=[PERS=2]] -> 'you'
... N[AGR=[NUM='sg', GND='m']] -> 'boy'
... N[AGR=[NUM='pl', GND='m']] -> 'boys'
... N[AGR=[NUM='sg', GND='f']] -> 'girl'
... N[AGR=[NUM='pl', GND='f']] -> 'girls'
... N[AGR=[NUM='sg']] -> 'student'
... N[AGR=[NUM='pl']] -> 'students'
... """
>>> grammar = grammar.FeatureGrammar.fromstring(g)
>>> tokens = 'these girls'.split()
>>> parser = parse.FeatureEarleyChartParser(grammar)
>>> trees = parser.parse(tokens)
>>> for tree in trees: print(tree)
(DP[AGR=[GND='f', NUM='pl', PERS=3]]
  (D[AGR=[NUM='pl', PERS=3]] these)
  (N[AGR=[GND='f', NUM='pl']] girls))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I managed to solve it by changing grammar = nltk.data.load('file:english_grammer.cfg') to grammar = nltk.data.load('file:english_grammer.fcfg')

Answer (score 1):

store the grammar with .fcfg extension and use load_parser in nltk package.

eg: english_grammer.**fcfg**

I used following code to load it.

```
import nltk
from nltk import load_parser
chart = load_parser('file:english_grammer.fcfg')
sent = 'the girl gave the dog a bone'.split()
trees = chart.nbest_parse(sent)
for tree in trees: print tree
```

That solve the issue for me.

Comment: Can you tell me where you stored the file english_grammar.fcfg?

Comment: I can't recall since I did this some time back. As I could remember, I gave the relative path. That mean store the file in the project location itself.